# ARM Assembly problem outputting correct string (or anything at all)

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to compare a user input number to 100, and if it is greater than or equal to 100, it prints "the number is greater than or equal to" and if it is less than 100, it prints accordingly. It takes the input part just fine, but the program immediately ends after the input is taken. I am very new to assembly, this is my second day working with it, so go easy on me. Thanks for any help!

```
.global main
main:

prompt: 
    ldr r0, = numPrompt
    bl printf   

get_input:
    ldr r0, =numInputPattern 
    sub sp, sp, #4
    mov r1, sp
    bl scanf
    ldr r1, [sp, #0]
    add sp, sp, #4

printinputasNum:
    cmp r0, #100    @compare num in r0 to 100
    bne Test1   @if not equal, jump to Test1
    ldr r0, = greaterorequalOutput 
    bl printf
    b   ExitAll
Test1:  blt Test2
    ldr r0, = lessthanOutput
    bl printf
    b   ExitAll
Test2:  ldr r0, = greaterorequalOutput
ExitAll:

myexit:
    mov r7, #0x01
    svc 0

.data

    .balign 4
    numPrompt: .asciz "Input a number: "

    .balign 4
    numInputPattern: .asciz "%d"

    .balign 4
    lessthanOutput: .asciz "The input number is less than 100 \n"

    .balign 4
    greaterorequalOutput: .asciz "The input number is greater than or equal to 100 \n"

.global printf
.global scanf
```

Comment: You load the number into `r1` but then use `r0` for the comparison. Also the `Test2` is missing the `bl printf` hence it doesn't print anything. Using `svc` to exit from a C style program is not recommended, either return or `bl exit`. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester Please post this as an answer.  [Comments are not a replacement for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments)!